# Wordpress-plugin Breadcrumb NavXT 7.1.0 creates unnecessary subsection from a get-request

Tags: ajax, wordpress, breadcrumbs, get-request

I use the Breadcrumb NavXT 7.1.0 plugin on the site.

An ajax-filter is implemented in the "News" section: when you follow a link like `mysite.com/news/?country=turkey`, only news about Turkey remains on the page.

```
/* frontend */
$(document).ready(function() {

    let slug = window.location.href.split('=').pop();

    $.ajax({
      cashe: false,
      method: 'post',
      url: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/news-ajax-sort.php',
      data: slug,
      success: function(data) {
        $('.all-news-wrap').append(data);
      }
    }); 
})

/* backend */
$keys = array_keys($_POST);
$newsslug = $keys[0];

if(isset($newsslug)) {
    $news_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'news',
        'posts_per_page' => 100,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'country_news',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $newsslug
            )
        )
    );
}
else {
    $news_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'news',
        'posts_per_page' => 100
    );
}
//here is the standard wordpress loop
```

At the same time, in the “breadcrumbs” the path is indicated to the main section:

**Home | News**

After a while, the task appeared to create a completely similar section "Events", only the ajax filter is not by country, but by year. It's a full copy of the "News", the settings in Breadcrumb NavXT are identical. But when following a link like `mysite.com/events/?years=2023` I get in the "breadcrumbs":

**Home | Events | 2023**

That is, there is a kind of transition to an unnecessary subsection, which in theory should not be (in any case, there is no such thing with the "News").

Why are sections that are absolutely identical in implementation handled differently by the plugin?

How does the plugin form a subsection from a get-request, and how can it be influenced?

I thought that maybe the problem was in the numbers, and substituted the word "events" in front of them (`mysite.com/events/?years=events2023`), but it didn't work. I got in the "breadcrumbs":

**Home | Events | events2023**

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck.
So leave a question, show us your code, what did you try and your research:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Borja, my question is why the plugin Breadcrumb NavXT works this way. What kind of code do you what to see?

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Borja, I think you don't know anything about wordpress and plugins. Therefore, please don't flood here, but leave this question to those who are able to answer it.

Comment: You don't even put the version of the plugin that you are using, you talk about an implementation but you don't show anything, do you know that a plugin also has code underneath and you can see and analyze it?
https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/breadcrumb-navxt
It is very easy to come here as a user and ask everything without to analyze and investigate the code you are using, but this is a programming forum, if you only limit yourself to using an application, this is not the place

Comment: @Borja, ok, I added the version of the plugin and my implementation code